# How to merge 2 images (border, actual image) with different sizes into 1 in linux

Tags: image-processing, command-line, imagemagick

I have around 2500 images. Some of them contains border while others arent. What I want to accomplish is to add border to the ones that doesn't have any.

Images with border are `64x64` and images without border are `56x56`

I prepared a border image file with size of `64x64` in PNG format and I want to merge all files without border within this image to get them borders and output them as PNG format aswell.

I have tried several ways using `ImageMagic` but no luck so far.

Comment: please try to be more clear by adding the images with border and without border so we can understand what you want to do.

Comment: The question itself is already clear and has been dealth with, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make a 64x64 lime-magenta gradient as `background.png` and a solid blue 56x56 image as `foreground.png` like this:

```
magick -size 64x64 gradient:lime-magenta background.png                 
magick -size 56x56 xc:blue foreground.png
```

Your command to paste the foreground into the centre of the background is as simple as:

```
magick -gravity center background.png foreground.png -composite result.png
```

[image]

Comment: That is also very nice solution and way better than mine since it doesn't require an effort to calculate pixels to center image, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out it's pretty doable with `convert` tool from the [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) package.

First I extracted all images with size of `56x56` to different location, then I did the following;

I added **4 pixels** on each side since my border is `64x64`

```
for image in ICO_*.png; do
  convert -page +0+0 border.png \
    -page +4+4 $image \
    -background none -layers merge +repage $image-withBorder.png
done
```